# Mailchimp & Groups

Tags: email, groups, smartgroups

I am testing out Mailchimp but want to keep the groups hidden from civicrm users. I tried smart groups but it will never remove the person from the group because that person still meets the search criteria of the smart group.

Are there any other options to have a "hidden" group to use for mailchimp?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the group? Might still work with MC even if disabled.

Answer (score 1):

What we normally advise users to do is create a smart group on top of the base groups for Mailchimp Sync. This is mainly to protect the base smart group, for instance if you have a smart group of active members and you linked that to Mailchimp directly then when someone unsubscribes from the group they would be unsubscribing from the active members group, which isn't correct. So we would normally recommend creating a Newsletter - Active Members or something along those lines and sync that group to Mailchimp. This then has very little effect for both sides if someone does decide the unsubscribe etc and the need to hide the group should reduced.